# A value of type 'Future<String>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'. Try changing the type of the variable

Tags: flutter, error-handling, token

I'm try to learn how to get token. What is wrong with the code I wrote?

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm try to learn how to get token.

import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

import '../common/constant.dart';

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you please add you full code instead of screen shot?

Comment: What is the declaration of the `setUser` variable? If you look at the first image, it is `String user`.....` It seems to be a variable declaration problem.

Comment: Where do you create a variable called `setUser`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this sample:

```
    class UtilSharedPreferences {
  static Future<String> getToken() async {
    var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs.getString('Token') ?? '';
  }

  static Future<bool> setToken(String value) async {
    var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs.setString('Token', value);
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String str = '';

  gettoken() async {
    str = await UtilSharedPreferences.getToken();
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    gettoken();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Text('Token :$str'),
          Center(
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                var result = UtilSharedPreferences.setToken('hi');
                if(result){
                  print('success');
                }
              },
              child: Text('save token'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: do you have any recommended articles on how to store tokens with shared_preferences library

Comment: you are using it correctly. This is the general way to do that.

Comment: how do i know that the token is actually saved?

Comment: Did you check my last update?! @AbdulAzizPermana when you save something the sharedpref return you a bool variable, you can check that and make sure you save your token

Comment: @AbdulAzizPermana Glad to hear that, if it was helpful, please approve it so other people find it easier.

Answer (score 0):

`Future` is asynchronous and you must use `await` to get the desired value.

```
user = await UtilSharedPreferencs();
```

The `async` keyword is required to use async. So implement it separately as a method

```
void setUser() async {
   user = await UtilSharedPreferencs();
}
void initState(){
  super.initState();
  setUser();
}
```

Comment: Future<void> initState() async {
    super.initState();

    user = await UtilSharedPreferences.getToken();
  }
sorry but error

Comment: Instead of making `initState` asynchronous, create and call `setUser` method asynchronously. See answer

Comment: still error and I'm a bit confused

Comment: what error did you get? @AbdulAzizPermana

Comment: Methods can't be assigned a value.

Comment: and The argument type 'void Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Comment: @AbdulAzizPermana Please add your modified code to your question

Comment: i'm sorry do you have reference or blog for save token use shared_preferences thanks.